# drupal_mail() is formatting my body

Tags: 7, emails, entities

[drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) is formatting my email body.
Before: http://pastebin.com/LbBy04BZ (note 1 line)
After: http://pastebin.com/nEx7AFwU (note multiple lines)

It should not, because Line 23 in [/modules/system/system.mail.inc](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/modules/system/system.mail.inc) is the following one:

```
$message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
```

How can I prevent the reformatting of my mail content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the API documentation for [drupal_mail_system()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system), there you'll have code to override the default [MailSystemInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/interface/MailSystemInterface/7).

For an exemple of how to override it, have a look at the [Postmark](http://drupal.org/project/postmark) module.
You can then redefine the `format()` function:

```
class YourModuleMailSystem implements MailSystemInterface {

public function format(array $message) {
  //remove this formatting.
  //$message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
  return $message;
}

//...
}
```